# Import sql structure from sql file which has data

Tags: import

I have a giant sql file that I created from my working server, but have had to shut that server down.

I'm trying to import the sql into my test server (very small). I just want to import the table structures from this sql file. I'm thinking something like a -no-data option. Is that possible?

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what database you are using. I'm thinking it may be mySQL.

If it was a sql dump, you would have table structure and inserts.

You can always delete any rows starting with "insert" and be left with just table creation, index creation and constraints.

If it's a recurrent task you are trying to script, we would need more information to help you.